# ASP MVC 5 (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity) User Management Package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Does asp.net mvc5 really not come with some sort of default controllers and views to manage your users? things like creating a new role, and then assigning it to a user etc etc?

Is every single mvc5 website supposed to code their own?
Over and over again?

I get that we can now add custom fields etc to our users, but surely some sort of simple base built in manager isn't asking for too much?

Is there some magical nuget package or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything like this.
I have added an item onto the asp.net uservoice list and you can vote for it there.
I'm marking this as closed.

http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/5009231-add-a-default-asp-mvc-5-microsoft-aspnet-identity